# Using a multiple words as a discord prefix with a space in between

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, prefix

I am trying to make my discord bot's prefix "Hey SkyeBot, ".

Right now I have tried to use:

```py
Bot(command_prefix='Hey SkyeBot, ", case_insensitive=True)
```

But it doesn't seem to work, meanwhile if I change it to "Hey " it does work. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This *does* work, but the issue here is that `case_insensitive` makes your `commands` case insensitive, *not* the prefix. As far as I know there's no way to do that. You can create a `list` of prefixes to have some variations to make it always work, like this:

```
prefixes = ["hey skyebot, ", "HEY SKYEBOT, ", "Hey skyebot, ", "Hey Skyebot, ", "Hey SkyeBot, "]
Bot(command_prefix=prefixes)
```

I recommend making a few variations, as people probably won't be changing case all the time manually. Just consider all lowercase, all uppercase, first letter capitalized (phone users), and first letter of each word capitalized.